# Is it a good idea to upload several files in parallel?

Tags: networking, internet, broadband

I am developing an application to upload several big files to a server from a home network.

I can select any of the following strategies:

1. Upload each file in sequence.
2. Upload all of them in parallel.

which one is faster, noting that the bottleneck is home network.

Comment: Try both and measure the results?

Comment: @multithr3at3d My test would be from one position, and I am looking to know the general concept that would be valid everywhere.

Comment: @man - "everywhere" is extremely broad.  Besides, you underestimate the validity, of a benchmark like that.  What applies to your connection, would basically apply to everyone, anyways

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You’re uploading to “a server”. What do you know about the server? Is there any possibility that it’s really a server farm, where the parallel connections are really going to different IP addresses?

Comment: @Scott It is a server farm in fact (google cloud server). Does it make any changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uploading in parallel will generally help get them all there faster, because if one of your upload TCP streams gets stalled for any reason, your other upload TCP stream(s) will be able to keep that bandwidth from going to waste.

Comment: Basically the same answer as mine, but more compact. :P

Comment: @LPChip *"Basically the same answer as mine"* -- The first sentence of your answer is the opposite of this answer's.  So you think that opposite answers are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, the answer would be:

> Six of one; half-dozen of another.

The reason is, if you reach a bandwidth bottleneck, it doesn't matter if you are uploading files one at a time or multiple at once; you are constrained by bandwidth.

What alters the answer is if there's an imposed speed limit for connections on one side.  This is seen on some regular content servers as well as those that use Torrenting protocol.

In this case, if the imposed speed limit is less than the max bandwidth on the home side, then it would make sense to transfer multiple files, up to the amount to cap out bandwidth on the home side.